# How to access docker data from linux wsl2

Tags: docker, wsl-2

I'm running Docker on windows using WSL2. The docker data directory can be access from windows using this path:

```
\\wsl.localhost\docker-desktop-data\version-pack-data\community\docker
```

But when I try to access the same folder from WSL, I couldn't find it.

From the linux terminal, I can find the following directory:

```
/mnt/wsl/docker-desktop-data/version-pack-data
```

However, it's empty! it doesn't show `community` folder or any other folders inside of it!

OS: Windows 11 build 10.0.22000.176
Docker: version 20.10.8, build 3967b7d
Docker Desktop: Version 4.0.0

Comment: Do`\\wsl$` on windows path bar and check if you have a folder with the name of linux SO (ex: Ubuntu-20.04)?

Comment: And then? Of course I do but that has nothing to do with what I'm asking about

Comment: Understood @menas. try copy files from one side to other as in [here](https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0383441) .

Comment: Same question found here with currently no answer: https://superuser.com/questions/1683586/access-docker-desktops-volumes-from-wsl2-bash

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, you have to re-mount it on a different path like this:

1. In powershell:

```
net use h: \\wsl$\docker-desktop-data
```

2. In wsl:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/yourdockermount
sudo mount -t drvfs h: /mnt/yourdockermount
```

Source: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/discussions/4176#discussioncomment-831817

The above worked for me. It was also suggested to do it in one step like so:

In wsl:
`sudo mount -t drvfs '\\wsl$\docker-desktop-data' /mnt/yourdockermount`

Source: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/discussions/4176#discussioncomment-1458301

Answer (score 1):

Slightly older question dusted off by [@ADJenks' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76177592/11810933), which certainly will work.

But IMHO a better solution is the one I detail in [this Super User answer](https://superuser.com/a/1778525/1210833).  Since that's a fairly long read, I'll repeat it here.  From inside a WSL2 distribution:

```
$ findmnt -a | grep "version-pack-data\s"
| |-/mnt/wsl/docker-desktop-data/version-pack-data        /dev/sdf[/version-pack-data]          ext4          rw,relatime,discard,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered
# Using the block device returned (sdf in this case):
$ sudo mount /dev/sdf /mnt/wsl/instances/docker-desktop-data -o X-mount.mkdir
$ cd /mnt/wsl/instances/docker-desktop-data
```

The advantage here is that you will be using the native Ext4 filesystem.  Using `drvfs` will not provide native permissions, symlinks, and other POSIX features.

Comment: lol, hello there... 

Answer (score -1):

WSL2 mounts to a different path.

The path you looked at on windows, if I'm not wrong, is for docker-desktop with wsl1. This is why the files look different.

The right path on windows will be this path (if you use Ubuntu-20.04 as your subsystem, if not look for the path of the subsystem you use):
**\\wsl$\Ubuntu-20.04\mnt\wsl\docker-desktop-data**

Comment: \\wsl$ or \\wsl.localhost it's the same thing. I'm using the latest version of windows 11 and the lastest version of docker and the path I mentioned above is the correct location of docker data folder from windows. But I'm asking how it looks like from the linux subsystem. The path you provided above isn't even a valid linux format because you're using the backslash rather than forward slash

Comment: It's a windows path.
Maybe it is a little different on windows11, but the problem is probably the same, the mount on the wsl is to a differnt path of the windows system. What you looked at on the windows path was probably created by the previous usage with docker desktop.
Try to look at \\wsl.localhost\ if there is the name of the subsystem and look there.